# ORMExecuteQuery: "(Entity) is not mapped"

Tags: orm, coldfusion

I have a `Users` Entity that is on several datasources, (same table just different data depending on what's calling it). Currently, depending on what section of the site calls the entity, it uses the datasource set in the `Application.cfc`.

I was recently asked to consolidate some of the pieces of the different sites into a single page. Because the entity is used in the different sections I am trying to avoid editing the component with the different datasources. So I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to set what datasource the entity uses on `entityLoad()`, or any other way around having to rebuild everything from scratch?

Comment: With how everything is developed in this application I will actually just have to figure out how to do it using coldbox, I just started with this company and am trying to push things away from coldbox and go strictly coldfusion since they have been introducing ORM themselves. Thanks for the help! @Henry

Answer (score 1):

Not with `EntityLoad(`), but `ORMExecuteQuery()` does support different datasource.

```
ORMExecuteQuery("from Artists", {datasource="#datasource#"});
```

https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ORMExecuteQuery

Comment: That's definately a step in the right direction, now its giving me the error " User is not mapped [from User]" my code is:  var users = ORMExecuteQuery("from User",{deleted=0},false, {datasource="ds1"});"

Comment: Does `entityLoad()` work before?  If not, try `ormReload()`.

Comment: No it still gives me the same error. It works just fine if I use the datasource the app uses but as soon as I change it to the source that holds the `Users` table I'm looking for it gives me the "User is not mapped [from User]" error.

Comment: Then I guess you need a clone of the `User` cfc, and an unique entity name in order for it to work.

Comment: `extends` means something more involved, if you just want property and methods but not setting up a parent/child relationship via ORM, make sure you use `mappedSuperClass`

Comment: `Users` is a child of the `BaseActiveEntity`. So it can see my datasource, but it seems like it cant find the entity `testUsers` or table `Users` in that datasource, which is weird because if I use a vanilla SQL statement I can get data back. So why cant ORM see it?